# React - trying to save fetched data in a variable but the variable returns empty

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, axios

I fetched json data with async await and i wanted to save the fetched data in a variable in order to be able to use it with a map in my component,
the data comes in properly inside the function - i checked with an alert , and also in the variable inside the function it does display all the data , but somehow the variable outside the function returns empty .
here is some code:
both alerts in the following code return the right data.

```
export let fetchPosts = [];
export async function FetchPosts() {
    await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(
        res => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(res.data))
            fetchPosts = JSON.stringify(res.data);
            alert(fetchPosts)
        }
    ).catch(err => {
        alert('err');
    })
}
```

```
import { fetchPosts } from '../services/post';
import { FetchPosts } from '../services/post';

export default function Posts() {
    function clickme() {
        FetchPosts()
    }
    return (<>
        <button onClick={clickme}>Click me</button>
        {fetchPosts.map((post, index) => (
            <div key={post.id} className="card" style={{ 'width': '16rem', 'display': 'inline-block', 'margin': '5px' }}>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h6 className="title">{post.title}</h6>
                    <p className="card-text">{post.body}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </>)
}
```

Comment: React is rendering before you fetch your data, and then has nothing telling it to re-render when data changes. You need a more comprehensive solution using state and effect hooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## State is the issue

React doesn't automatically reload on your singleton `fetchPosts`.
Instead, try...

```
export function FetchPosts() {
    return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
}
```

then

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FetchPosts } from '../services/post';

export default function Posts() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    function clickme() {
        FetchPosts().then(res => {
          setPosts(res.data);
        });
    }
    return (<>
        <button onClick={clickme}>Click me</button>
        {posts.map((post, index) => (
            <div key={post.id} className="card" style={{ width: '16rem', display: 'inline-block', margin: '5px' }}>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h6 className="title">{post.title}</h6>
                    <p className="card-text">{post.body}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </>)
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-almeida-q4331?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

If you want global state, that's another topic you should dive into entirely but you can do it with a singleton, you just need to incorporate it with hooks and an event emitter.  I have a bit of a hacked version of this here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-h8rpu but you should probably stick to redux or mobx or AppContext which is more of a popular pattern.

Comment: Does the `async` keyword on FetchPost make any difference here?

Comment: I tried doing it but it through me an error :
TypeError: _services_post__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.FetchPosts.then is not a function

Comment: @HåkenLid you are right. I accidentally left this. My bad.

Comment: if i understood correct your question - in my .then res i get the data and it shows it in the alert correctly

Comment: but it still gives me this error
×
TypeError: _services_post__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.FetchPosts.then is not a function
clickme
`
  30 | export default function Posts() {
  31 |     const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  32 |     function clickme() {
> 33 |         FetchPosts.then(res => {
  34 |             setPosts(res.data);
  35 |         });
  36 |     }`

Comment: @Mindy ha ha found it and corrected. I called it without the function. Updated. https://q4331.csb.app/